# Turn php loop output to variable?

Tags: php, ob-start

I am still learning php and this is how i convert php loop statement output to variable::

```
ob_start(); 
if 2 > 1 {
echo 'It is OK';
} else {
echo 'It is not OK';
}
$myvar = ob_get_clean();

echo $myvar;
```

Now the $myvar will output above if result, but is there better approach in doing this?

Comment: Why echo it if you want to use it later? Why not just put it in a variable immediately?

Comment: why not do like this:-https://eval.in/850728

Comment: I just gave an example of how i put it into a variable, i am reusing $myvar later on something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there is no looping in your code: `if/else` blocks are executed once, not in a loop.

Second, if you want to save the string, you can assign it to your variable directly, using many approaches:

**if/else**

```
if(2 > 1) $myVar = 'it is OK';
else      $myVar = 'it is not OK';
```

**switch case**

```
switch (2>1):
  case true: 
    $myVar = 'it is OK';
    break;
  default:
    $myVar = 'it is not OK';
endswitch;
```

**ternary operator**

```
$myVar = 2>1 ? 'it is OK' : 'it is not OK';
```